# How do I use NSTimer to countdown from 10 seconds then stop the timer?

Tags: swift, nstimer

This is what I have so far.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var countLabel1: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var start: UIButton!

 var count = 10

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self.start, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

 func update() {
    if(count > 0) {
        countLabel1.text = String(count--)
    } 
 }

 func timerFinished(timer: NSTimer) {
    timer.invalidate()
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the timer as a var in your class:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
```

Create the timer in viewDidLoad:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Update than will be called every 0.4 second (more or less):

```
func update() {

if(count > 0)
{
    countLabel1.text = String(count--)
} else {
 timer.invalidate()
}}
```

Edit: [If you want to get update called every second put 1 instead of 0.4 of course.]

Comment: This will not count down from 10 to 0 seconds.

Comment: He put 0.4 so I assumed he wanted it to count 10 times not each second.

Comment: @dasdom why not? it can be easy to adopt, isn't it? just set 1.0 sec and not 0.4 sec as the time interval and set counLabel1.text initially to "10"

Comment: I also assumed that he'd have put the initial value in the storyboard. Of course both of my assumptions can be wrong.

Comment: What do i do for the count variable. It hasn't been called yet. (sorry i'm new to this)

Comment: @dasdom do i set the count variable equal to 10

Comment: @vale I wanted it to decrease by 1 and start at 10.

Comment: You already set it to 10 using var count = 10 and in update count-- already des creases it by one each time update is called.